# Docker-compose in Rider running dotnet where it is not needed

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, rider

I have docker-compose that running only one service and it is etcd.

```
version: '3'

services:

etcd:
  container_name: mvscp1-etcd
  image: hidden/mvscp1.etcd.dev:latest
  environment:
    - ETCD_ROOT_PASSWORD=hidden
    - ETCD_READONLY_USER=hidden
    - ETCD_READONLY_USER_PASSWORD=hidden
  ports:
    - "32379:2379"
```

and when it starts I see that Rider is trying to debug it as it dotnet application. When I ran docker inspect etcd command, I do see next:

```
"Path": "/riderDebugger/runtime-dotnet.sh",
    "Args": [
        "/riderDebugger/JetBrains.Debugger.Worker.exe",
        "--mode=server",
        "--frontend-port=57005",
        "--backend-port=57105"
```

my entrypoint is obviously overriden by Rider. And etcd is failing constantly because of that.
How can I tell rider to ignore that particular docker-compose entry and do not debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (as of v. 2020.3) Rider cannot detect whether a service is .NET Core executable or not, so it has to override entrypoints for each service.
We'll try to fix it in the coming versions. Here is [the tracking issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-56654).

Comment: Thanks, I've read that in help after posted that question. What would you think would be better: to leave this question to hang to help others or remove it as it temporary issue?